# How to Cleanup FK Legs in MOCAP. Need them to stick to ground

Tags: animation

How to Cleanup FK Legs in MOCAP. Need them to stick to the ground.

For example, if we capture motion capture and FK legs mostly move on the ground. I want them to stick on the ground.

In Maya it is easy. We create a locator and parents to bones. Or Use a Snapping tool.

But how to clean up FK legs in Blender?

Thank you.

Comment: Try this tutorial: https://youtu.be/OcBfIklWpgA if it doesn't help, then check for other videos of this guy's channel, since he has a few more Mocap cleanup videos that could help

Comment: Ya but it won't work for me. Thank you anyway